# How to join the result of a request to another table (to add column)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max, greatest-n-per-group

**Edit**

I have two tables : etape and etapex.

[image]

[image]

I need to find the maximum `idProjet` for each `idEtape` (in table etapex), and there link the `idEtape` and `idProjet` to 'nomEtape`and`livrable` from the table etape.

So I tried two different things :

```
SELECT etapexprojet.idEtape, idProjet, nometape, livrable
FROM etape, etapexprojet
WHERE etapexprojet.idetape = (SELECT MAX(etape.idetape) FROM etapexprojet )
```

Unfortunately, this is what I get :

[image]

Here's my other "solution":

The first step is to find the max value (I don't want to use group by) :

```
SELECT EX.idEtape
FROM etapexprojet EX                   
LEFT JOIN etapexprojet EX2       
  ON EX.idprojet = EX2.idprojet 
  AND EX.idetape < EX2.idetape
WHERE EX2.idetape IS NULL
```

But now I'm stuck, and I don't get how to join what I get from that first request to the table etape.

At the end, it should give me something like :

[image]

But with the columns `nomEtape` and `livrable` as well...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `JOIN` the `etape` table to the results of your first query:

```
SELECT EX.idProjet, E.*
FROM etape E
JOIN etapexprojet EX ON EX.idEtape = E.idEtape              
LEFT JOIN etapexprojet EX2       
  ON EX.idprojet = EX2.idprojet 
  AND EX.idetape < EX2.idetape
WHERE EX2.idetape IS NULL
ORDER BY idProjet
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc9b20/3)

Answer (score 1):

There are various solution to this greatest-n-per-group problem.

One simple method is to start from this aggregate query that gives you the maximum `idEtape` per `IdProjet`:

```
select idProjet, max(idEtape) idEtape from etapex group by idProjet
```

Then you can simply join this with the original table:

```
select e.*, p.idProjet
from etape e
inner join (
    select idProjet, max(idEtape) idEtape from etapex group by idProjet
) p on p.idEtape = e.idEtape
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ET.idEtape, ETX.idProjet, ET.nomEtape, ET.livrable
FROM etape  ET               
LEFT JOIN etapexprojet ETX ON ET.idEtape = ETX.idEtape 
WHERE ETX.idEtape = (SELECT MAX(idEtape) FROM etapexprojet WHERE idProjet = ETX.idProjet);
```